# Webdriver io autocomplete in VS Code

Tags: selenium, visual-studio-code, webdriver-io

I'm using Webdriver IO as the e2e testing framework. But this autocomplete issue is really slowing me down. **VS Code doesn't auto complete the global variable `browser` and it's methods.**

**.eslintrc**

```
{
    "extends": ["eslint:recommended", "standard"],
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "plugins": [
        "mocha",
        "webdriverio"
    ],
    "env": {
        "webdriverio/wdio": true,
        "mocha": true
    },
    "parserOptions": {
      "ecmaVersion": 8,
      "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "rules": {
        "indent": ["error", 4]
    }
}
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"],
  "plugins": [
    ["transform-runtime", {
      "polyfill": false
    }]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use TypeScript typings.

Add 2 dependencies to package.json:

```
"@types/node": "^8.5.2",
"@types/webdriverio": "^4.8.7",
```

Install them, reload project. If autocomplete does not yet works, create 
tsconfig.json in root of your project:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "./.built/"
  }
}
```

You don't need to use typescript compiler, it will just provide autocomplete. Continue writing your js code as usual.

But if you wish to use typescript, here is small beginner guide:
http://webdriver.io/guide/getstarted/configuration.html#Setup-TypeScript

Comment: oh wow, I feel so stupid now, I had the typescript version worked but I removed the dependencies after converting to ES6... Thank you so much!

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thank You very much. At the time of this writing, there is an issue with the latest versions of the above packages. Install the versions mentioned in the answer.